# Get Thrift Field Type from ID

Tags: java, thrift

Is there a way to get the type of a parameter using the thrift ID? I have data coming in that needs to go to one of 6 different Thrift objects so I'm using reflection to instantiate the appropriate object and set data fields.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(package + table.name);
Object o = cls.newInstance();
Method getField = cls.getMethod("fieldForId", int.class);
Object field = getField.invoke(o, thriftId);
Method setField = cls.getMethod("setFieldValue", field.getClass(), Object.class);
setField.invoke(o, field, data);
```

The variable `data` is a String. This code works great until it comes across a field with a type other than String where I can get `ClassCastException`. I tried doing this:

```
Method getFieldValue = cls.getMethod("getFieldValue", field.getClass());
System.out.println(getFieldValue.invoke(o, field).getClass.getName());
```

But for String, getFieldValue returns null if they are blank and you can't get the class. I could assume that all null values are Strings, but that seems dangerous considering Lists, Maps, etc are probably returned as null as well.

I also tried getting the Class of the field but it just comes back as the Enum (_Fields) which is expected.

Comment: As the type should be fixed for a given field, what about setting up a simple field-ID based mapping table on your own?

Comment: Eventually I'm going to have up to 150 objects types, each with 30+ fields. I'd rather not write all of those mappings. Getting the type of the object is fine, it's discovering the type of each field within the object that's giving me trouble.

Comment: How do you fill in the `data` for these objects? All by reflection?

Comment: I have an array (read in from a delimited file) and array index corresponds with thrift field 1, for instance. So I get the field for ID 1 and set it to what's contained in fields[0]. Reflection only comes into play because I don't know which thrift object I need until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Grab the name of the field then get that field.

```
Method getFieldName = field.getClass().getMethod("getFieldName");
String fieldName = (String) getFieldName.invoke(field);
Class<?> fieldType = cls.getField(fieldName).getType());
```